# Logic Question with who has a key and truth

Tags: logic, contest-math

Four people are standing infront of a treasure chest, each makes a statement. One statement is false, the other three are true.

Ann: "I do not have the key and Cal does not have the key."

Ben: "I do not have the key and Ann does not have the key."

Cal: "I do not have the key and Ben does not have the key."

Don: "I do not have the key ans Ann does not have the key."

Who has the key?

I really struggled to answer this question, I couldnt even get a truth table because it is so confusing. Please can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest bypassing truth tables and simply asking "who has the key"?

If no one has the key, then they are all telling the truth, so excluded.

If Ann the key, then Ann, Ben, and Don are lying, so excluded.

If Ben has the key, then Ben and Cal are lying, so excluded.

If Don has the key, then only Don is lying, so the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Ann, Ben and Cal are all mentioned at least twice, however Don is only mentioned once (by himself). Supposing Don has the key, he is lying and the other three must therefore be telling the truth; whereas if anyone else had they key, both they and at least one other person would be lying. So Don must have the key.

If you wanted to express this in a truth table, suppose $A,B,C,D$ represent Ann, Ben, Cal and Don having the key, respectively. The table will have four rows and four columns:
$$\begin{matrix} A & B & C & D & | & \neg A \wedge \neg C & \neg A \wedge \neg B & \neg B \wedge \neg C & \neg A \wedge \neg D \\ \hline
T & F & F & F & | & \cdots &&&\\ \hline
F & T & F & F & | & \cdots &&&\\ \hline
F & F & T & F & | & \cdots &&&\\ \hline
F & F & F & T & | & \cdots &&& \end{matrix}$$

You need to pick whichever configuration makes exactly one of the remaining four columns false.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to use a truth table is to calculate the truth value of a sentence under various scenarios.  For example, in this case 
\begin{array}{cc|c}
\hline 
A & B & A\vee B \\ \hline
\top & \top & \top \\ 
\top & \bot & \top \\
\bot & \top & \top \\ 
\bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\end{array} 
each row represents a possible state of the world (paramaterized by the truth values of the atomic formulas $A$ and $B$).  The value in the right hand column is the truth value of the disjunction $A\vee B$.

How can we adapt this framework to your question?

Well, there are four possible states of the world: $A$ has the key, $B$ has the key, $C$ has the key, or $D$ has the key.  And instead of a single sentence to test, we have to test each of the four claims.  So our table looks like this:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline
\textrm{Who has the key} & A\textrm{'s claim} & B\textrm{'s claim} & C\textrm{'s claim} & D\textrm{'s claim} & \\ \hline
A & & & & \\ 
B & & & & \\ 
C & & & & \\
D & & & & \\ \hline
\end{array}
where the right-hand columns are the truth values of the four claims. You just need to fill in the sixteen truth values, and find the row with three $\top$s and one $\bot$.

I'll get you started.  $A$'s claim is that $A$ does not have the key and $C$ does not have the key. This statement is true if $B$ or $D$ has the key, and false otherwise. So the first column looks like this:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline
\textrm{Who has the key} & A\textrm{'s claim} & B\textrm{'s claim} & C\textrm{'s claim} & D\textrm{'s claim} & \\ \hline
A & \bot & & & \\ 
B & \top & & & \\ 
C & \bot & & & \\
D & \top & & & \\ \hline
\end{array}

---

If you want to be a little more formal about it, you can expand the labels on the table a little. Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be the atomic formulas saying that $A$, $B$, $C$, or $D$ has the key, then the table can look like this:
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \neg A \wedge \neg C &  \neg A \wedge \neg B & \neg B \wedge \neg C & \neg A \wedge \neg D \\ \hline
\top & \bot & \bot & \bot  & \bot & & & \\ 
\bot & \top & \bot & \bot  & \top & & & \\ 
\bot & \bot & \top & \bot  & \bot & & & \\
\bot & \bot & \bot & \top  & \top & & & \\ \hline
\end{array}

You should see that this table is identical to the one above, except with slightly different labels.  Each row is a possible world, and you have to identify which is the world where exactly one person is lying.

Comment: Of course, you don't have to use a truth table method.  In which case, the first paragraph of Clive Newstead's answer tells you all you need